# Every continuous homomorphism $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is of the form $x \mapsto x^n$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, fourier-analysis, topological-groups

I wanted to ask if anyone knew of a simple way to prove this.

The proof I know: Identify any such character with a continuous, periodic homomorphism $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow S^1 \subset \mathbb C^{\ast}$.  Then $f$ has a Fourier expansion
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_n c_n e^{2\pi i nx}$$

with

$$c_n = \int\limits_{\mathbb R/\mathbb Z} f(x)e^{-2\pi i nx}dx = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if $f(x) = e^{2\pi i nx}$} \\ 0 &\textrm{else} \end{cases}$$

This shows that if $f$ is not any of the $e^{2\pi i nx}$, it is zero.  $\blacksquare$

This proof could be considered circular, because the Fourier expansion of $f$ is essentially using the Peter-Weyl theorem, which says that the characters of a compact topological group form an orthonormal basis for the $L^2$ space.  So we are essentially already assuming that $f$ is one of the $e^{2\pi inx}$.

How can this be proved without using Fourier series/circular reasoning?

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123588/varphi-in-operatornamehoms1-s1-are-of-the-form-zn

Comment: Any homomorphism $\Bbb{R/Z} \to \Bbb{C}^*$ is an homomorphism $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}^*$. You are supposed to know they are of the form $f(x) = e^{ax}$. And $f(0) = f(1)$ implies $a = 2i \pi n$.