# Homomorphisms $U(1) \to SU(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

I am trying to understand why the conjugacy classes of (continuous) homomorphisms $U(1)\to SU(2)$ are given by the maps
$$ \phi_n : z\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} z^n & 0 \\ 0 & z^{-n} \end{pmatrix}, \quad n \in \mathbb Z. $$
Here two homomorphisms $\phi,\psi : G \to H$ of groups are said to be conjugate if $\phi(g) = h^{-1}\psi(g)h$ for some $h\in H$.

Of course, I can see that each $\phi_n$ is a homomorphism, and it is necessary to assume that $n$ is an integer in order for this map to be well-defined and smooth. What I do not understand is why every other homomorphism $U(1) \to SU(2)$ is conjugate to some $\phi_n$.

One idea is to use the spectral theorem to write
$$ \phi(z) = h^{-1} D h, $$
where $h\in SU(2)$ and $D = \text{diag}(w,w^{-1})$ for some $w\in U(1)$. Now this would be good enough if $h$ can be chosen to be constant and independent of $z$, since then the problem reduces to finding endomorphisms $z\mapsto w$ of $U(1)$, and I know these are given by $z\mapsto z^n$ (see e.g. [$\varphi$ in $\operatorname{Hom}{(S^1, S^1)}$ are of the form $z^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123588/varphi-in-operatornamehoms1-s1-are-of-the-form-zn)). But I do not understand how or why $h$ can be chosen independently of $z$ here.

Comment: Hint: One approach is to first solve the problem on the Lie algebra level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrices in the image commute and thus are simultaneously diagonalizable, so indeed the same $h$ works for all.

Comment: Ah yes, $U(1)$ is abelian of course. Thanks!